# Vaadin 8 - widgetset

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, vaadin, vaadin8

I added Vaadin google maps addon to my Spring boot project. If I want to display map on site, then I get error:

> Widgetset 'com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet' does not contain an
>   implementation for com.vaadin.tapio.googlemaps.GoogleMap. Check the
>   connector's @Connect mapping, the widgetset's GWT module description
>   file and re-compile your widgetset. In case you have downloaded a
>   vaadin add-on package, you might want to refer to add on instructions

If I add `@Widgetset("com.vaadin.v7.Vaadin7WidgetSet")` annotation to UI class, then I get this error:

> Failed to load the widgetset:
>   ./VAADIN/widgetsets/com.vaadin.v7.Vaadin7WidgetSet/com.vaadin.v7.Vaadin7WidgetSet.nocache.js?1521722356809

And I have a question: How should a widgetset look like, how to build it? I was looking for examples and tutorials but I still can't do this.
I read that in early Vaadin versions, I should do a manual compilation widget, but in version 8 compiling is automated.
Maybe this is important information, but I use gradle not maven.
Please help me, because I am trying to fix it for a week.

Comment: Do you have the project or parts of it somewhere in public repository? Would be easier to say what might be the cause.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you include add-ons in your Vaadin project, you need to compile the widgetset and the widgetset needs to include the add-on widgetsets.

I have the following *src/main/resources/widgetsets/AppWidgetset.gwt.xml* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Vaadin//DTD Vaadin 7//EN" "https://raw.github.com/vaadin/gwt/master/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
    <inherits name="com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet"/>

    <!-- include widgetsets of external add-ons here -->
    <inherits name="org.vaadin.hene.popupbutton.widgetset.PopupbuttonWidgetset"/>
</module>
```

This includes the Vaadin PopupButton add-on. Of course you need to adapt it to include your desired add-ons. My gradle build looks like:

```
configurations {
    vaadinAddOns
    widgetSetCompilation
    themeCompilation
}

dependencies {
    themeCompilation('com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter')
}

task compileWidgetSet(type: JavaExec) {
    // execution of Vaadin GWT compiler
    classpath configurations.vaadinAddOns
    classpath configurations.widgetSetCompilation
    classpath file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/widgetsets")
    main = 'com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler'
    args '-war', "${projectDir}/src/main/resources/VAADIN/widgetsets"
    args '-strict'
    args '-logLevel', 'WARN'
    args 'AppWidgetset'
    jvmArgs '-Xmx1024M'

    doLast {
        // clean up unnecessary stuff
        file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/VAADIN/gwt-unitCache").deleteDir()
        file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF").deleteDir()
    }

    // for the up-to-date check of gradle
    outputs.dir("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/VAADIN/widgetsets/AppWidgetset")
}

clean.dependsOn cleanCompileWidgetSet
processResources.dependsOn compileWidgetSet

// on-the-fly theme compilation is disabled in Vaadin production mode, so we do the compilation ourselves
task compileThemes {
    def themesFolder = file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/VAADIN/themes")
    new FileNameFinder().getFileNames(themesFolder.toString(), '**/styles.scss').each { path ->
        def themeFolder = file(path).getParentFile()
        def fileIn = new File(themeFolder, 'styles.scss')
        def fileOut = new File("${buildDir}/resources/main/VAADIN/themes/${themeFolder.getName()}/styles.css")
        dependsOn tasks.create("compileTheme${themeFolder.getName().capitalize()}", JavaExec) {
            classpath configurations.themeCompilation
            main = 'com.vaadin.sass.SassCompiler'
            args fileIn, fileOut
            inputs.dir(themesFolder)
            outputs.file(fileOut)
        }
    }
}

processResources.dependsOn compileThemes
```

And finally the annotation:

```
@Widgetset("AppWidgetset")
public class MyUI extends UI {
    ...
}
```

This is a lot of manual stuff. You can omit the theme compilation if you do not run in Vaadin production mode for now. I am almost sure that there is a Vaadin gradle plugin out there that simplifies the widgetset and theme compilation but when I was looking for it it didn't match my requirements.

Btw: Vaadin 7 widgetset is not appropriate for Vaadin 8 :)

Answer (score 1):

I sounds like your project is missing build setup for Vaadin extensions requiring client side extensions (aka custom widgetset). This happens often with new Spring users as start.spring.io don't currently support adding third party Maven plugins. Addin vaadin-maven-plugin and doing full build should fix the issue.

To see a Spring Boot project with vaadin-maven-plugin configured, I suggest to use the [viritin-spring-archetype](https://github.com/viritin/viritin-spring-archetype) and see the generated project (and especially the pom.xml generated by the project). You can also manually copy the relevant parts from the official plain servlet project template (generated by the default archetype or IDE plugins).

When using Gradle the fix is similar in nature. If you created the project using start.spring.io, you can just add the [gradle-vaadin-plugin](https://github.com/johndevs/gradle-vaadin-plugin) to your project, by adding follow snippet to your build.gradle file, e.g. after buildScript section:

`plugins {
    id 'com.devsoap.plugin.vaadin' version '1.3.1'
}`

You will also need to declare dependencies with client side extensions as follows (use google maps coordinates instead):

`vaadinCompile("org.vaadin.addon:v-leaflet:2.0.6")`

Comment: OP: "Maybe this is important information, but I use gradle not maven."

Comment: Oh, my bad, didn't read the question to the end :-) I'll try to find time to fix the answer.

Comment: But should not vaadin in this version, he should not compile it himself?

Comment: I have a widgetset, but I dont know how to compile this widgetset in gradle.